# Setting a primitive data type through the use of a Field object

Tags: java

Is there any way to set the value of a primitive through the use of fields? I've tried to play around with the following, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
temp[i].setInt(new Object(), new Integer(data[0]));
```

In this case temp would be an array of declared fields. The current index i holds a field that holds a primitive int value. Is this sort of thing even possible?

Comment: What is the type of `temp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Map` of field names and values called `fieldValues`, and you want to set the values on an instance called `myObject`, this code would check the respective primitive type, then set its value appropriately.

```
for (String fieldName : fieldValues.keySet())
{
    Field field = myObject.getClass().getField(fieldName);

    if (field.getType().equals(Integer.TYPE))
    {
        field.setInt(myObject, Integer.parseInt(fieldValues.get(field.getName());
    }
    else if (field.getType().equals(Long.TYPE))
    {
        field.setLong(myObject, Long.parseLong(fieldValues.get(field.getName());
    }
    else if (field.getType().equals(Boolean.TYPE))
    {
        field.setBoolean(myObject, Boolean.parseBoolean(fieldValues.get(field.getName());
    }
    // more else branches for each needed primitive type
}
```

Comment: This is in a static context so I can't use this. The data that I'm working with comes from a text file. The field name and data are saved in it. I search the class for the field name and then set it's value with the corresponding data. I have to resort to figuring out the type of each field and then creating a subclass of numbers to store the data.

Comment: Done. Tell me if this helps.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how this could work. In your example what does the instance of Field represent? In my case would it just be one of the fields in my array of fields? Also what does myObject represent? I've never really done this sort of thing so I may be using the set method incorrectly.

Comment: Added more code. `myObject` is the object instance you want to set your values on. If you have no instance, i.e. you are setting static fields, just replace `myObject.getClass()` with `Class<INSERT YOUR CLASS NAME HERE>`, and all other occurrences of `myObject` with `null`.

Comment: You can't pass null instead of a reference to an object.

"If the specified object argument is null, the method throws a NullPointerException."

Comment: No, that is not true. If the field is a static field, this is the way to do it. Only if the field is not static, but you try to set it with null as instance, will you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Okay well I got it to work for a field that is in the class I'm working on. I also need to do this for fields that this class inherits from. Why wouldn't something like this work?

superTemp[j].setInt(Player.class.getSuperclass(), Integer.parseInt(data[0]));

Comment: The first parameter of the setInt method specifies the *instance* on which to do the setting, not the class. If you want to set static fields, you just put null there. If you want to set fields from superclasses too, just make sure that they are included in your superTemp array.

Comment: superTemp specifically contains super class fields. I just tried using null, superTemp[j].setInt(null, Integer.parseInt(data[0]));, and it throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: Then the field you are trying to set is not static. You can check that a field is static by doing `if (field.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC != 0)`

Comment: The fields aren't static so how would I get around it? I tried using what I used for the non static fields in the subclass, but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, if the field isn't static, you need to specify on which instance you want to set them with the first parameter of the setInt method. OR you simply ignore non-static fields and do not set them at all.

Comment: Pretty sure I'm being extremely stupid, but how is this, temp[i].setInt(Player.class, Integer.parseInt(data[0]));, different from what I posted earlier in regards to passing the instance.

Comment: Once again: The first parameter specifies on what object (not class!) you want to set the field value. For non-static fields, you specify the instance on which to set the field here. For static fields, you just give null. You DO NOT give it a class object here, because that will attempt to set the value on a field of that name ON THE CLASS OBJECT, instead of on the class itself. You do appear not to really understand the concept of the keyword `static`.

Comment: I understand the use of the keyword static. It makes the method or variable a class method or variable meaning only one copy of it exists despite there being multiple instances of objects of the class. I think what I'm really having trouble with is what you mean by the instance.

Comment: Which means you did not understand the concept of the keyword `static` ;-) Normally, a class specifies sort of a blueprint. Of that blueprint, you can have any number of reproductions. Those reproductions are called instances. For example, the most simple class is `Object`. So I can have `Object a = new Object();`, which means I have an instance of Object, called `a`. I can also have an instance of `Object` called `b` by doing `Object b = new Object();` *HOWEVER*, anything that is *NOT* static, is not specific to a or b, it lives on the `Object` class itself.

Comment: This means that a non-static field will be competely different on `a` and `b`. Also, this means that a static field will be exactly the same on `a` and `b`, since it does not live on those, but on the class. Now, coming back to `Field.setInt`, for a non-static field, you would give `a` or `b` as the first parameter for a non-static field. But for a static field, these do not matter. In fact, `setInt` would not allow these. So, for static fields, you give `null` as the first parameter.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What instance am I supposed to pass for setting the fields of the super class when there is no instance declared? I also can't pass and instance of the subclass I am working in because the method is declared in a static context so that it can be used without needing more than one instantiate of the current subclass. That's why I used Player.class for the subclass fields, which works. So how do I specify an instance of the superclass when there isn't one explicitly declared?

Comment: Damn you for keeping me from my well-deserved sleep. Anyway, the answer is: You don't. Either you have a specific instance, or you don't. If you do not, and your code complains about having to set field values without having an instance, you simply ignore any field that is non-static. As stated before, this can be done checking if a field is static by doing `if (field.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC != 0)`. The only other option is, if you really want to set fields that are not static, you need to instanciate your class, plain and simple. `MyClass obj = new MyClass(); field.setInt(obj, 5);`

Comment: Sorry for keeping you awake! Thank you for all the help!